# Which encryption protocol does Firebase use?

Tags: c, ssl, firebase

I'm pretty new to Firebase. Right now I want to modify a Firebase using an embedded client I'm developing in C. For the encryption I'm using cyaSSL.

The question is, which encryption protocol does Firebase use?  Which is the format of the messages that Firebase is expecting from me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing a C embedded client for Firebase. I'm also using CyaSSL.
I have succeeded connecting with CyaSSL 3.3.0 with AES or DES3 cypher. When AES and DES3 are both disabled (NO_DES3 and NO_AES defined in cyassl\ctaocrypt\settings.h) connection fails.

Maybe you have a better answer, you asked 7 months ago. I would comment your question but I still haven't got 50 reputation.

Regards